# Find the symmetric matrix $P$ for the subspace generated by $v_1$ and $v_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ the vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with $dim(V)=2$,
> generated by the vector:
>
> \begin{align*} v_{1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 
>  -1\\  1 \end{pmatrix}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ v_{2}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 
>  -1\\ 
>  -1 \end{pmatrix} \end{align*} Find the real symmetric matrix $P\in \mathbb{R}^{3x3}$ that is the projection over $V$, i.e., $P^{2}=P$ and
> $Pv \in V$ for every $v \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$
>
> *Hint:* $v_1$ and $v_2$ generates a plane in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with a certain normal vector $n$. $Pv$ must be orthogonal to $n$ for every
> $v\in \mathbb{R}^{3}$

I'm not sure how can I find $P$ and even more how can I use the hint. Can you help me please? I would really really appreciate it.

**Update:**

Okey! I've found that the matrix must be of this form:

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
a & d &0 \\ 
d & e &0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Also, we know that $P=P^{2}$ so:

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
a & d &0 \\ 
d & e &0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}=&\begin{pmatrix}
a^2+d^2 & ad+de &0 \\ 
ad+de & d^2+e^2 &0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\iff a=e=1 \text{ and, } d=0\\ \\ &\therefore P=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 &0 \\ 
0 & 1 &0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

$v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent, hence $\{v_1,v_2,n\}$ is a basis of $ \mathbb R^3.$

Then define the linear operator $T: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ by

$Tv_1=v_1, Tv_2=v_2$ and $Tn=0.$

If $P$ is the representation matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis of $ \mathbb R^3$, then $P$ will do the job.

Calculate $P$ !

Comment: Thank you for your help! Please, please can you check my update on my publication to verify if the matrix I've found is correct? Thank you very much! @Fred