# Find the symmetric matrix $P$ which is the projection on $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, projection

I'm dealing with the same problem as in this question: [Find the symmetric matrix $P$ for the subspace generated by $v_1$ and $v_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3863628/find-the-symmetric-matrix-p-for-the-subspace-generated-by-v-1-and-v-2)

But I do not fully understand the answer given in that question. Could someone give me a hint on how to solve the following problem?

> Let $V$ the vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with $dim(V)=2$,
> generated by the vector:
>
> \begin{align*} v_{1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 
>  -1\\  1 \end{pmatrix}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ v_{2}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 
>  -1\\ 
>  -1 \end{pmatrix} \end{align*} Find the real symmetric matrix $P\in \mathbb{R}^{3x3}$ that is the projection over $V$, i.e., $P^{2}=P$ and
> $Pv \in V$ for every $v \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$
>
> *Hint:* $v_1$ and $v_2$ generates a plane in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with a certain normal vector $n$. $Pv$ must be orthogonal to $n$ for every
> $v\in \mathbb{R}^{3}$

I know that a normal vector to $v_1$ and $v_2$ is $n=v_1 \times v_2 = (2,2,0)$ but I'm not sure how to proceed with the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is a normal vector then $P$ is given by
$$Pv=v-{1\over \|n\|^2}\langle v, n\rangle n$$
Indeed, $\langle Pv,n\rangle =0$, hence $Pv\in V$ and  $$P^2v=Pv-{1\over \|n\|^2}\langle Pv,n\rangle n=Pv$$

Comment: Thanks!! that's indeed a direct answer! Taking $n=(2,2,0)$ i got $P =     \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0\\
    -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix} $ Which indeed satisfies the desired conditions and also $Pv \in V$ for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$

Answer (score 1):

So your projection is a map $P: \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow V$ that assigns $v\in \mathbb{R}^3$ to its projection on $V$, meaning you need to find a way to write what it does concretely; so, use the hint. $n=(2,2,0)$ is orthogonal to $V$ and as such, $\mathscr{B}=\{v_1,v_2,n\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then, your map takes $$v=\sum_{i=1}^3 c_i e_i, \hspace{2mm} e_i \in \mathscr{B}, c_i \in \mathbb{R}$$ to $$Pv=c_1 v_1+c_2 v_2$$
And now you're done. Just pick your favorite basis, feed it to $P$ and assemble the result in columns. For example, picking $\mathscr{B}$, I get as a matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 &0 & 0 \\0 &1 &0 \\ 0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$
but you can also feed it the canonical basis and get something else.